# Symfony's Validation Component (Standalone)

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently using Symfony's validation component as a standalone tool. I'm building an API using Lumen and Doctrine2, and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to use the UniqueEntity constraint outside of the Symfony2 framework. I've followed [this example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) to attempt to use the UniqueEntity, but I notice that the namespace `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity` doesn't even exist in the standalone package. Has anyone else gotten this work, or do I have to write my own uniqueness validator?

Answer (score 0):

I create the validation with a yml, you can also create intro model.

In my case this is example:

```
# src/SClinicBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Cf\SClinicBundle\Entity\CfIndicationsTemplates:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: name
            message: cf.indications_template.name.unique
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: { message: "cf.indications_template.name.not_blank" }
            - Length: { min: 2, max: 100, minMessage: "cf.indications_template.name.min_length", maxMessage: "cf.indications_template.name.max_length" }
        templateIndication:
            - NotBlank: { message: "cf.indications_template.templateIndication.not_blank" }
        status:
            - NotBlank: { message: "cf.indications_template.status.not_blank" }
            - Choice: { choices: [0, 1], message: "cf.indications_template.status.choices" }
        datetimeR:
            - DateTime: { message: "cf.indications_template.datetime_r.bad_datetime" }
Cf\SClinicBundle\Entity\CfReportTemplates:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: name
            message: cf.report_template.name.unique
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: { message: "cf.report_template.name.not_blank" }
            - Length: { min: 2, max: 100, minMessage: "cf.report_template.name.min_length", maxMessage: "cf.report_template.name.max_length" }
        status:
            - NotBlank: { message: "cf.report_template.status.not_blank" }
            - Choice: { choices: [0, 1], message: "cf.report_template.status.choices" }
        datetimeR:
            - DateTime: { message: "cf.report_template.datetime_r.bad_datetime" }
Cf\SClinicBundle\Entity\CfMedicalStudy:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: name
            message: cf.medical_study.name.unique
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: { message: "cf.medical_study.name.not_blank" }
            - Length: { min: 2, max: 100, minMessage: "cf.medical_study.name.min_length", maxMessage: "cf.medical_study.name.max_length" }
        administerDosesZone:
            - NotBlank: { message: "cf.medical_study.administerDosesZone.not_blank" }
        status:
            - NotBlank: { message: "cf.medical_study.status.not_blank" }
            - Choice: { choices: [0, 1], message: "cf.medical_study.status.choices" }
        datetimeR:
            - DateTime: { message: "cf.medical_study.datetime_r.bad_datetime" }
```

You can reviewer my example and try compare with you code.

Comment: Jose, thank you for your answer, but I'm trying to find a way to use this validation outside of Symfony. This appears that you are using validation in the context of Symfony, and not as a standalone tool? Correct me if I'm wrong though. I may just go the 'create a custom constraint / validator rule' route if it is not possible